# Custom IBundleTransform seems to be cached on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm trying to implement a dynamic bundle that gets resent on every request. I found a guide on how to achieve this at: http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/10/aspnet-45-mvc-4-revisiting-IBundleTransform-in-bundling.html

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. The CustomTransformType.Process gets called only once. I want it to run on every request. The browser cache is not the issue (check the included picture).

[image]

My implementation is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace DynamicBundleTest
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            Bundle myBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/MyBundle", new CustomTransformType());
            myBundle.Include("~/path/to/file");
            bundles.Add(myBundle);
        }
    }

    public class CustomTransformType : IBundleTransform
    {
        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
        {
            context.UseServerCache = false;
            response.Cacheability = HttpCacheability.NoCache;
            response.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the Process method called only once, even though `context.UseServerCache` is set to `false` and `response.Cacheability` is set to `HttpCacheability.NoCache`?

Comment: I've done exactly the same thing and get the same issue..